# Дополнительная информация при наведении на ссылку

Tags: php, css

Здравствуйте.
На страничке вывожу ссылки из базы данных, в итоге появляется на странице список вида:

> Ссылка 1
>
> Ссылка 2
>
> Ссылка 3
>
> Ссылка 4
>
> Ссылка 5

и т.д., список большой.

Вывожу методом

```
while ($my_link = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_link)) {

<div class="link"><a href="$my_link[url]">$my_link[name]</a></div>

if ($my_link['photo'] != NULL) {
   <div class="link_ph"><img src="/photo/$my_link[photo]"></div>
}

}
```

Как вы уже поняли исходя из кода, под каждой ссылкой выводится фото.
Так вот, я хочу сделать чтоб фотография под ссылкой появлялось лишь в том случае, если на ссылку навели курсором мыши.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь в решении этой задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

css:

```
div.link_ph {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 z-index:5
}

div.link:hover + div.link_ph {
    display: block;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="link"><a href=''>name</a></div>
<div class="link_ph" ><img src="url"></div>

<div class="link"><a href=''>name</a></div>

<div class="link"><a href=''>name</a></div>
<div class="link_ph" ><img src="url"></div>
```

[демо](https://jsfiddle.net/4j3veycs/)

Comment: Не подскажете еще, как сделать чтоб можно было навести курсором на появившееся изображение? Сейчас же только тяну курсор на изображение - оно тут  же пропадает

Comment: я это умею только так, может гуру скажутт, что не очень правильно - просто добавьте в css `div.link:hover + div.link_ph, div.link_ph:hover`

Comment: что-то не работает этот способ у меня)) вот так сделал **div.link:hover + div.link_ph, div.link_ph:hover {
    display: block;
}** может что не так?

Comment: @Денис если между ссылкой и картинкой отступ, то линк:ховер пропадает.

Comment: @Денис https://jsfiddle.net/4j3veycs/1/

Comment: Может стоит обернуть и ссылку и картинку к ней в div и событие hover  делать на него? Тогда еще один hover можно повесить на картинку...